# building a search form in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to make search customer form for access 2010.

I like to have an option group based on a query search. I made a search query looking for first name or last name. two textboxes are also present on the form to fill up the query inputs (1st and last name)

I need option group so that I can select the resulted name for booking purposes.

In the past I have made an indirect way of doing this using subform and a checkbox.
Then loading both results on a subform and checkbox (requery) so the user only has to select on the checkbox. But this time I want the options to be the query result itself! Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with using a combobox or a listbox?

Comment: Would it be nice that from the result (option group) I can directly select any record and when I press the button "Next" it carried over the data to next form.

Instead of having two "result" objects (subform and checkbox). It's redundant.

Comment: My customer search form works similar to this:  I have one search textbox at the top.  I have a continuous form of all the customers underneath.  After the user enters text in the search box, I have it filter the recordset by creating a criteria based on each field name like so: `FirstName Like *%s* Or LastName Like *%s*` and replace `%s` with the text in the search box.  I think it's pretty nifty.  The user then clicks on an arrow button to the right of the contact name to select or view that contact in full detail view in a new form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple example that uses a List Box:

Table: Clients

ID - AutoNumber
LastName - Text(255)
FirstName - Text(255)
Email - Text(255)

Test data:

```
ID  LastName    FirstName       Email
--  ----------  --------------  ------------------
1   Thompson    Gord            gord@example.com
2   Loblaw      Bob             bob@example.com
3   Kingsley    Hank            hank@example.com
4   Thompson    Hunter S.       hunter@example.com
5   Squarepants Spongebob       ss@example.com
6   O'Rourke    P. J.           pj@example.com
7   Aldrin      Edwin "Buzz"    buzz@example.com
```

Form layout:

[image: DesignView]

VBA module for this form:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.lstSearchResults.RowSource = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Me.lstSearchResults.SetFocus
Me.lstSearchResults.Value = Null
Me.lstSearchResults.RowSource = _
        "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName FROM Clients " & _
            "WHERE LastName LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.txtSearchLastName.Value) & _
                "*"" AND FirstName LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.txtSearchFirstName.Value) & "*"""
End Sub

Private Function DQ(s As Variant) As String
' double-up double quotes for SQL
DQ = Replace(Nz(s, ""), """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
End Function

Private Sub btnLookupEmail_Click()
If IsNull(Me.lstSearchResults.Value) Then
    Me.txtEmail.Value = ""
Else
    Me.txtEmail.Value = DLookup("Email", "Clients", "ID=" & Me.lstSearchResults.Value)
End If
End Sub
```

When the form is first opened, everything is empty.

[image: FirstOpened]

Typing "thompson" (without the quotes) and clicking `btnSearch` populates the List Box with clients `WHERE LastName LIKE "*thompson*"`. (If you look at the code you'll see that it will also match on FirstName if you supply one.)

[image: SearchResults]

Select one of the items in the List Box and click `btnLookupEmail` and the email address is displayed in the Text Box below.

[image: EmailFound]

Comment: This is awesome.  I didn't realize that it can be also be done using listbox. I am not quite in the know about using SQL codes but I do clearly understand the code. <br/>

But is it possible using frameset(option grp) instead? <br/>

My program will hide the current form when user press 'Next' (assuming he selected a resulted value. So that, I can carry over the selected value into the next form using full link form address, "forms!formname!object.value".  Is it possible to use currentvalue of a list box for the next form?<br/>

Comment: @Daytron re: "Is it possible to use currentvalue of a list box for the next form?" - I don't see why not. `forms!formname!lstSearchResults.Value` should work if `formname` is still loaded, even if it is hidden. A List Box is designed to hold a variable number of possible selections, whereas an Option Group is really intended for a fixed number of choices.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. Last question, I found out too late some line I don't understand.  <br/>
From the syntax for the Replace function: 
  <br/>Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )
  <br/><br/>
Why do you have to replace and why the string is Nz(s,"")?

Comment: @Daytron The `Nz()` function converts Null values to the specified non-Null value. In this case it is saying "If s is Null then treat it like an empty string". The `Replace()` ensures that any `"` characters in the string are doubled up, as they must be when the string itself is enclosed in double-quotes, e.g., `"Say ""Hello"" for me!"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! All up and running now.